# In Onenote, how do I 'make text in image searchable' enabled by default?

Tags: images, search, microsoft-onenote, ocr

OneNote has a great OCR feature where you can select an image and click `make text in image searchable`.

But I'd like this enabled by default for all images I paste into OneNote - is this possible? (*currently it seems hit and miss - I often have to right click on each images I want made searchable*)

Answer (score 3):

It is enabled by default. Check under Options to make sure:

`File` → `Options` → `Advanced` → `Disable text recognition in pictures`.

It *does*, however, take time to do. It is done by a background task so it can take a while.

Comment: In my case this option was already disabled, but images were not searched by default. Enabling and then re-disabling this option helped (with onenote restart after each change).